# React Native - Fetch API response.text()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a two way communication between a server and an app (client).

Stringified response.text() returns this... Is there a way that I can make it return the text only? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ask is not clear. What is the issue you are facing? Server response will always be string. It could be valid Json/xml or plain text. If you want to use it as JSON.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I wanted to ask if there's a method that will return "LED status: ON/OFF" string only, without other text that is seen on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with substring() and indexOf().